# Update Swagger during runtime

Tags: node.js, swagger, loopbackjs, swagger-ui, swagger-node-express

In my internship we are developing an API for a website to control various products. Each product has a so called connector that exposes the different endpoints that can be used for that product.

When we add a new product, we have to restart the application in order to expose the api endpoints. After this point Swagger is also updated and will display new API endpoints.

Because we have lots of new products we want to integrate, I'm developing a way where I can configure new product endpoints using a JSON template. I can verify that these endpoints work by calling them directly. Unfortunately, Swagger is not updated with the new API endpoints.

**Question**

Is it possible to update the API endpoints that Swagger displays when the program is already running? We are using NodeJS and LoopBack.